# Set user to inactive in genexus access manager

Tags: genexus, genexus-gam

I want to set a specific user to inactive in genexus access manager. Is there a way to do that?

I saw this [link](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?22082,GAM%20Users) where you can undelete the user but how can you include the deleted user in the grid where you can click a button to undelete him/her?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a good approach for this is not to delete the user but to block it, like this:

```
&GAMUser.Load(&UserGAMId)
&GAMUser.IsBlocked = true
```

Later, if you want to enable the user again, you just change "IsBlocked" to "false". Also if you want to show them on a grid, you could check by this property and unblock them by clicking some button.

Hope you find this info useful.

Comment: Hi @Chona, thanks for your input. I saw that GAMUser has IsActive property. Do you know why we can't set it to false?

Comment: Yes, you cannot set it to false because that property is used for the scenario in which the user registers for the first time. "isActive" means: 

(true = the user is active on the system).
(false = account needs to be activated by the admin).

I think that for your use case, the best option is to use "isBlocked" insted.